# java efficient repainting on moving objects

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, repaint

I'm wondering what's the most efficient way of repainting in my case, and how to go about it.

I've got a `JFrame`, containing a `JPanel`. This `JPanel` contains a some AWT graphics. Some of these graphics are fixed, they don't move. Some other graphics (on top of the fixed graphics) in this panel do move. The layout is updated every 3 seconds. The fixed graphics require quite a bit of math to draw, so I probably don't want to repaint all graphics, but only the moving ones.

This is the possibilities I came up with:

1. To put the fixed graphics and the moving graphics in two separate panels and only repaint one panel, which are layed over each other.
2. To add two different `Graphics` objects to the panel (one for fixed graphics and one for the moving) and only repaint one graphics object. (is this even possible?)
3. Perhaps some other way I don't know?

Comment: *"The fixed graphics require quiet a bit of math to draw.."*  Draw them to a `BufferedImage` and draw the image first.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Then I still have to repaint the BufferedImage every time, right?

Answer (score 3):

Like others are saying, use a `BufferedImage` for the fixed object.  For the moving objects, you should calculate the bounds of the area that needs to be redrawn (i.e. old bounding box union w/ new bounding box for all objects that moved).  Blit the fixed graphic section of that area down first, and then blit the moved object(s).

You should also look into [double buffering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics) if you haven't already.  It is generally a better experience to do drawing to an offscreen buffer and then flip to the screen when ready.

Answer (score 2):

If the background is never changed in the lifetime of the window, then you can do all the complex computations once at construction time and create a `BufferedImage` object for it.

Then in your repaint, draw the image onto the graphics object using

```
graphics.drawImage( bufferedImage, ... )
```

This should be much faster than recomputing the background every repaint since you are reusing the same `BufferedImage` over and over again.

**EDIT**
If the window is resized  you can scale the bufferedImage if that's good enough for your purposes by using the

```
boolean Graphics.drawImage(Image img,
   int dstx1, int dsty1, int dstx2, int dsty2,
   int srcx1, int srcy1, int srcx2, int srcy2,
   ImageObserver observer);
```

method where the coordinates are the current size of your window.

If you need to recompute the background image on a window resized you can add a listener to listen for resize events.

```
this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() 
{  
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {           
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you make sure the BufferedImage is recomputed when the window is being resized?

Comment: *"..is recomputed when the window is being resized?"* Does it need to be recomputed, or just stretched to fill the new size?  *"Then I still have to repaint the BufferedImage every time, right?"*  Sure, but painting an image is very fast.

Comment: @Xander updated answer to address your resize question

Comment: I implemented this solution, but I lose a lot of quality when I draw my graphics to a BufferedImage and then to the panel, compared to directly drawing it on the panel. Why is this? Do you have any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: sounds like your buffered image isn't a good size compared to your panel? Perhaps scaling is making the image too blocky? If so maybe try my second solution of recreating the bufferedImage when the component is resized